# How to Add +1 on Number using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to change the value of this

```
<font id="invited" size="3" color="red">1</font>
```

I mean add +1 so it became 2..

I have this javascript code

```
function group(b){
for (a = limit_limit1 = 0; a < b.data.length; a++)
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/member/1234?method=post&access_token=" + access_token,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "POST",
    success: function() {
        limit_limit1 += 1
        //alert("Done");
        "HERE I want to make code here to add +1 on html id(invited) above."
    }
})
}
```

Comment: As it says in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) -> `<font>` - **Do not use this element!** _Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5._

Comment: @Vucko— **all** styling elements? Not [*b*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/text-level.html#the-b) or [*i*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/text-level.html#the-i). ;-)

Comment: @RobG as you can see, I just c/p the article from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). But yes, it seems that the docs from MDN aren't the same as the ones from W3 :)

Comment: @Vucko—MDN is a public wiki that anyone can contribute to, whereas W3C is an actual standards body. I'll get around to fixing that page sometime… ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Change your element and add css separately.

```
<span id="invited">1</span>
```

Then using jQuery:

```
success: function() {
    limit_limit1 += 1
    //alert("Done");
    var inv = $("#invited");
    inv.text(limit_limit1); 
}
```

Comment: @Hardik You've changed the result of the code (the original value of the element is ignored).

Comment: @VincellCandelaria can you confirm that `limit_limit1` is what you wanted inserted by the `success` function

Comment: @SimonH I don't know.. but what I only want is to add +1 value on $("invited") every success function call.. and the code above works fine..